# Premiere Pro imports audio/video unlinked

Tags: premiere

I import clips into the project and when I drag them into the timeline, the clips have video & audio unlinked, which is very annoying for editing.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle on Linked Selection to have Premiere Pro respect the linked status of clips:

[image]

[copied from community.adobe.com](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/premiere-imports-audio-video-unlinked/m-p/10020219)